# Find parameter $k_f$ for which steady-state error equals $0$

Tags: control-theory

[image]

$u(t)=t, G_0(s)=\frac{k_p}{s}, G_R(s)=k_f$

Find parameter $k_f$ for which steady-state error equals 0

Finding $E(s)$

$$E(s) = U(s)*\frac{1}{1+\frac{k_p}{s}*k_f} = \frac{1}{s^2+k_pk_f*s}$$

Steady-state error:

$$\lim\limits_{s \to 0} s*\frac{1}{s^2+k_pk_f*s}=\lim\limits_{s \to 0} \frac{1}{s+k_pk_f}=\frac{1}{k_pk_f}$$

So there's no $k_f$ that exist that would fulfill the requirements, but apparently that's wrong somehow.

Could anyone tell me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: Where does $k_f$ come from? I guess that you actually mean that $G_R(s) = k_f$?

Comment: Yes, I have already edited it

Comment: what answer are you expecting? Generally a P-controller does not give zero steady-state error.